# How can I convert a floating point number to an integer in python?

Tags: python, floating-point, integer

I have given an input of 3 arguments to a script from powershell and I want one of these to be the floating point number 0.0. I then try to convert this value from a string to an integer using time = int(time) but I get an error. Anyone know how I can get my variable inside the program to hold my float point number? 
Thank you.

Comment: `time = int(time)` works just fine if `time` is a floating-point number. If it's a string representing a float, you have to convert it to float first: `time = int(float(time))`. Please show us your code, and the actual error traceback—or, better, an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) demonstrating the problem that we can run ourselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
time = int(float(time))
```

Are you sure you want an integer here? It doesn't make sense to pass in `"0.0"` if you want integer `0`. It sounds like either you should be passing in `"0"`, or you should be storing it as a float.

To store it as a float, just use

```
time = float(time)
```

Comment: How do I store it as a float, this is the problem I am having I think!

Comment: @TerrorMing: I have no idea why that would confuse you, but I've extended my answer anyway.